# Notgetting full body message of Gmail API with Python

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to read the access code from gmailAPI, coded is not fetching the full/complete message body.I am using Python code for it

I tried using various formats to fetch the complete message like Raw and Full

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import dateutil.parser as parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import base64

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
       if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)



     results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
     messages = results.get('messages', [])
          if not messages:
         print("No messages found.")
     else:
         print("Message snippets:")
         for message in messages:
             msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
             print(msg['snippet'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected Result:You requested a one-time access code to log into your member account. Please enter the following access code within the next 10 minutes, and click Submit:
Your One-Time Access Code: 8627816
This is an automated email. Please do not reply to this message. If you have any questions, please contact Optum GovID IT Help Desk. 
Thank you,
Optum GovID

Actual:
Access Code Notification You requested a one-time access code to log into your member account. Please enter the following access code within the next 10 minutes, and click Submit: Your One-Time Access

Note:Original message(Expected) has many spaces and e.t.c

Comment: `msg['snippet']` I doubt this will return the entire message text.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You are retrieving a snippet of the message rather than the full message body.*

#### Explanation & Fix:

As per the Users.messages Resource Documentation of the Gmail API, the `snippet` is "A short part of the message text.". In order to get the full message, you need to get the `raw` message and decode it as it is returned in `base64`.

In your `for` loop, you need to replace:

```py
for message in messages:
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
    print(msg['snippet'])
```

with:

```py
for message in messages:
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
    body = base64.b64decode(msg['raw'])
    print(body)
```

#### References:

- [Users.messages Resource and methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource)

Comment: @ommse2etestGovid Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please accept the answer that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too :)